# \foreach and \StrLen

Tags: foreach, lengths

I don´t know how to make a foreach with a StrLen inside it, is it possible?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,hidelinks]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand \nveics {2}

\newcommand \alfanumchassi {136564765}
\newcommand \alfanumchassib {36564765}

\ifdef{\alfanumchassi}{\StrLen{\alfanumchassi}[\chassi]}{}
\StrLen{\alfanumchassib}[\chassib]

% \foreach \n in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{
% \IfStrEq{\csname \x \endcsname}{s}{\global\renewcommand \furtodanoimovel {n}}{}
% }

\begin{document}

{\chassi}\\

{\chassib}\\

\end{document}
```

If I comment "\StrLen{\alfanumchassib}[\chassib]" and uncomment "\foreach \n in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{..." I have a lot of errors.

Comment: Could you tell us what you're trying to do? One thing I noticed is that `\csname\x\endcsname` is kind of weird. Either you'll get the unusual control sequence `\\x` or you wanted to write `\expandafer\csname\x\endcsname` to get a control sequence named by the string returned by `\x`. But where do you expect `\x` to be defined? I'm confused.

Comment: @wrtlprnft `\csname` does full expansion until finding the matching `\endcsname`; no need to use `\expandafter`.

Comment: @egreg: interesting, I'm sure I've seen this construction a couple of times… Thanks for clearing that up! Edit: never mind, that was probably always the other way around (e.g. expanding `\csname` before a `\def`).

Answer (score 1):

It's quite hard to guess what you're trying to do.

1. You have `\foreach \n` and use `\x`
2. `\csname\x\endcsname` is probably an error, because it would usually be something undefined
3. `\global\renewcommand` won't do a global redefinition
4. In your code `\furtodanoimovel` is not defined, so `\renewcommand` would raise an error anyway.

Here is a version that might do what you want:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand \nveics {4}

\foreach \x in {b,...,\alphalph{\nveics}}{
  \IfStrEq{\x}{c}{\gdef\furtodanoimovel{n}}{}
 }

\begin{document}

\texttt{\meaning\furtodanoimovel}

\end{document}
```

[image]

As you see, the macro `\furtodanoimovel` has been defined.

Comment: I disagree with point 2 (or maybe I'm too tired): isn't `\csname x\endcsname` the same as `\x`? You have an extra backslash there.

Comment: @wrtlprnft Yes, you're right

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, the script inside the foreach was wrong, the correct is to put \StrLen inside it, this gives me an error and I don't know how to make it or using another command similar to \StrLen for this case.

There is a difference in using \x or \n in \foreach? I thinked that I could use any command like \w, \z or anything that doesn't exists.

Comment: (disregarding the fact that this is not an answer) you can use any possible macro name, you just have to be consistent about which you use. `\foreach \x in {1,...10} { \n }` is not going to work.